# How to add on click event for button that appeared on mouseover

Tags: javascript, image, button, mouseover

I have two questions:

1. I want to display 6 buttons around an image on `mouseover` event of the image on specific positions. Is it possible?
2. Is it possible to write an `onclick` event for those buttons?

I don't have any experience in web designing. I used the below code

**Javascript:**

```
function showIt(imgsrc)
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').src=imgsrc;
document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='';
}

function hideIt()
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='none';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="imageshow" Onclick="onClickFunc()" style="display:none" value="Button1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="imageshow" Onclick="onClickFunc()" style="display:none" value="Button2"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="imageshow" Onclick="onClickFunc()" style="display:none" value="Button3"/><br>
<img src="Images/Image1.jpg" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)"><br>
<input type="button" id="imageshow" Onclick="onClickFunc()" style="display:none" value="Button4"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="imageshow" Onclick="onClickFunc()" style="display:none" value="Button5"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="imageshow" Onclick="onClickFunc()" style="display:none" value="Button6"/>
```

but when I `mouseout` from the image, the button is disappearing. If i remove the `onmouseout` event, the button stays like that only which i don't want to. And I really didn't get on how to place 6 buttons around the image. I am planning to do like this:
[image]

So kindly help me. Thank you

Comment: everything possible ..you did anything/some code?? if yes then paste it..

Comment: please push your code for better understanding

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, what you have to do is define all six button as you want and set property in style `display:none` and when you will over the mouse on  the image and when you wand to show all six images then call a function `onmouseover` and set the `display:none` property `display:''` in this way when you will mouse over on the image all the images will get displayed

2nd you may write the `onClick` with each button and it will work fine.

Hope will work for you.

This will be the code for each button out of six

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" Onclick="onClickFunc()" style="display:none" value="Button1" />
```

Comment: But the buttons will disappear onmouseout. If i don't write the onmouseout event, they are staying like that only. How to overcome this problem

Comment: no, when you will mouse-over to that image, in javaScript you will change the display property from none to empty i-e(display: ). this will show your all six button and those will not disappear again even if you don't want to hide them again.

Comment: if you want to hide them again on mouse-out the write another function onMouseOut and just set the display:none again and it will again hide the buttons.

Comment: If i use display:empty, it is still staying. What i meant is, the buttons should hide when the cursor range crosses the button. Please tell me if i am not clear

Comment: You are using document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='block';
 where you should use document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='';

Comment: Ok.Thank you. Now i am able to click the button. But how to hide them on mouseout if i don't clik on them. I want to implement both the functionalities

Comment: No. It's not working and also, i am able to add only one button. Please refer to the modified code above

Comment: I didn't get why am i able to add only one button. Can you tell me why is this happening

Answer (score 1):

Yes Why Not !!!

1. I want to display 6 buttons around an image on mouseover of the image on specific positions. Is it possible? 
   ANS :- give every button same class like 'imgBtn' and make it by default display none. At the time of mouse oven on image you can write code

in jquery like :-

```
jQuery('#imageID').hover(function(){
    jQuery('imgBtn').show();
})
```

in javascript :

paste this line on img tag in

```
onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName("redText").style.visibility = 'visible';"
```

---

1. Is it possible to write an onclick event for those buttons? I don't have any experience in web designing. So kindly help me. Thank you

ANS:   yes  you can write any function on onclick on button like :

```
jQuery('#buttonID').click(function(){

    //button functionality
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as a background for one div. Inside that div create another one div and write the code for 6 buttons in it.

Normally set `display:none` for this buttons div, While hover that image from javascript function you can set `display:block` from javascript then that six buttons will display on the image.

The following is the code for witing onclick event for button.

```
<button type="button" Onclick="alert('hai')">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the only solution that comes to my mind is making use of image maps and jquery.

I have built a rough demo, you may have to enhance it as per your requirements.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mL6rd/)

All the boxes except the one in the center is an image map. When you hover you mouse over any of the image maps, I show a button with the help of jquery.

Comment: Please refer to the image i've uploaded and suggest me the solution