# How to display content with onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

I'm creating a mega menu for a wordpress site.
On hover I want it to display certain content depending on what item you've hovered.

I've managed to write some code to achieve the hover effect but the content disappears before it's clickable due to the onmouseout function

Here is a sample of my code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
var y = document.getElementById("support");
  if (y.style.display === "block") {
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function customerSupport() {
  var x = document.getElementById("support");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (y.style.display === "block") {
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onmouseover="myFunction()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('myDIV').style.display = 'none';">Try it</button>
<button onmouseover="customerSupport()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('support').style.display = 'none';">Customer Support</button>

<div id="support" style="display:none">
Hello World
</div>
<div id="myDIV" style="display:none">
<button>Try it now!</button>
</div>
```

Is there a way to allow me to click the displayed content without it disappearing?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248185/10703114

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your HTML so that your 'Try it now!' content remains inside the container of your mouseover/mouseleave function like the below:

```
<div onmouseover="myFunction()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('myDIV').style.display = 'none';">
 <button>Try it</button>
 <div id="myDIV" style="display:none">
  <button>Try it now!</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Working JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/59L06jtu/

Comment: This wont work since I'll be adding multiple elements later on and will need to be in a separate div